# Change _id from ObjectId to normal unique auto increment integer

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am pretty new to Django and web development so all of this is new to me as I am learning.

I recently had a Django site setup and working with Postgresql. When I created it, I over complicated things and needed to use Postgresql specifcally because of one of the fields it had that SQLite did not have. Anyways, I am going to redo it (v2) and want to convert to a MongoDB. Right now I have everything set up but I noticed when I create new items from my models in the admin panel, it gets `_id:ObjectId("61ba69238db76b91b4bf42f1")` in the database. I am guessing this is the primary key? However, Django from my understanding is looking for a normal integer value. So when I am trying to remove things or modify things it gives me the error: `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.`

Should I be creating my own "id" field for each model? Should/can the default `_id` field be used?

Thank you!

Comment: The fields `id` and `_id` are not the same.  Perhaps you need to add the id field when you create the record?

Answer (score 0):

> In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique _id
> field that acts as a primary key.

[The _id field docs.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field)

"_id" field is always in the mongo collection. If you do not explicitly provide "_id" field in your model like this:

```
_id = djongo_models.ObjectIdField()
```

then you could not query for it from djongo.
And if you do not provide any field which is marked as a primary_key, then djongo will help you and provide you with

```
id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
```

You can check it in the migration files. Djongo also makes an unique index for this field. So you will end up with two unique indexes, one is "_id" which is bson ObjectId and the second one is "id" which will be a sequenced integer.
And if you have autofield "id" added by you or djongo behind the scenes, you should be able to filter by "id" like:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(id=1).delete()
```

So you don't need to add "id" field, djongo will make it for you.
And "_id" field will be always in the mongo collection, you can ignore it or add it to your model, and use it (query).